# make omnifun default in vim insert completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, eclim

after installing eclim and ycm in vim, when you start typing vim will use `-- user defined completion` in the popup menu, you can switch to Omni completion, which set up to display eclim options with c-x c-o.

How do I make vim user Omni completion options and not user defined option by default without having to press c-x c-o every time ?

if I understand correctly the chain should go:

completefunc  -(calls)>  omnifunc  -(calls)> eclim options

instead completefunc is calling user defined completion by default, and will switch to omnifunc on c-x c-o

Comment: That's a ycm setting, try the documentation. Also, why don't you simply use eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the default `<C-n>` completion (whose sources can be configured via the `'complete'` option), Vim has *two* custom completions, namely *user* and *omni* completion. The only difference is in the trigger keys (`<C-x><C-u>` vs. `<C-x><C-o>`) and option names for the function names. To use the omnifunction with the userfunction keys, simply re-assign the function name *after the omnifunc has been set*:

```
:let &omnifunc = &completefunc
```

Comment: I tried that as also mentioned in the previous answer, however when this is set the popup menu will not appear while typing as it use to do. you need to trigger it.

Comment: Well, that's then an issue with YCM; I guess it provides the auto-completion.

Comment: There is another difference between 'user' and 'omni' completion. I think user-completion is global across all files, whereas omni-completion is based on filetype

Comment: @mikew No, both are / can be buffer-local.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I said nothing about being buffer local.

Comment: Thanks for the `<C-x><C-u>` shortcut, I knew the omnifunc, but not the completefunc one.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my current ~/.vim/vimrc:

```
" Eclim + YouCompleteMe {{{1
" See <~/MyDocs/SysAdmin/Eclim.otl>
" This next line recommended by Eclim installation instructions

autocmd FileType php,java,ruby let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'

" For your list of filetypes where you want Eclim semantic completion 
" as the default YCM completion mode:

autocmd FileType php,java,ruby,c,cpp,perl,python  
    \if &completefunc != '' | let &omnifunc=&completefunc | endif

" This will allow you to hit <Enter> in normal mode to search for the
" word under the cursor

nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <cr> :PhpSearchContext<cr>
" End Eclim + YouCompleteMe }}}1
```

I found that I needed to have &omnifunc = &completefunc when I want to use
Eclim's semantic completion.

I am not sure I understand completely but, it looks like Eclim expects omnifunc
and YCM expects completefunc, where
    User completion = completefunc
    and
    Omni completion = omnifunc